# iOS 5.1 and Xcode 4.3.1 CodeSign Error

Tags: xcode, ios5.1

I just downloaded the iOS 5.1 and the Xcode 4.3.1. But when I'm going to test in my device, the Xcode give me the error:

> CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 5.1'

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Sorry, I have to ask. Are your provisioning profiles set up and installed?

Comment: Sure. The error was shown after installation of iOS 5.1

Comment: Alright well then +1 I can't seem to get my Xcode to generate the same problem. Good Luck!

Comment: Btw, iOS 5.1 update erased developer profiles on my device and I had the same error message in Xcode. 
Have you checked for profiles after update?

Comment: You mean the iPad "Provisioning Profiles"? Yes, it is like before the update.

Comment: Solve this. [Just change the iOS Deployment Target to iOS 5.1](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2250/_index.html)

Answer (score 18):

Try assigning your provision code in every fields like the below picture.
I had same issue after upgrading to the iOS 5.1 and the Xcode 4.3.1, but it started working fine after I tried this.

assign all provisions like this just once. (or try changing "any SDK" to "iOS5.1"
[image]

Previously, I was doing like this.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I already solve this. +1 for the attention. ;-)

Comment: @jj0b, Just change the iOS Deployment Target to iOS 5.1, https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2250/_index.html;

Comment: Also thing to you, @Aky. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2250/_index.html

Comment: @Non Umemoto: Thanks.  Solved it for me.  Was doing my head in.

Comment: that is not really solving it now is it. What you have done is cut out all devices with lower IOS's, which in my opinion is a no-go. Support for "as old as you can go" is my personal take. also Non Umemoto's answer is correct, you have just wrongly put some codesigning.

Comment: I was able to keep my version at 4.3, then just set all of the fields as shown in the screenshot.  But I didn't have an adhoc setting.  It worked for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should revoke your certificate and make a new certificate request from Keychain access. make new certificate and install it. you don't really need to create new provision profile the existing one modify and select the certificate newly created but you must download updated provision profile and install to xcode.

everything works perfectly for me. hope this could hlep.